# Inheritance misfit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

I ' m having 3 classes, A, B and C

```
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
};
```

However, C has to be derived from A, and B meantime:

I did:

```
class C : public A, public B
{
};
```

But it didn't work!

Comment: `class C : public B {};` would make `C` derive from both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Is it caused by the extra : after A?

Comment: What didn't work? What was the error msg? Add more detail please.

Comment: Also add your reasoning. Is multiple inheritance what you are going for or are you actually attempting single inheritance incorrectly? The`:` is incorrect syntax as @NeilKirk stated.

Comment: Write the minimal code which you think is valid that generates the error and quote the error.

Comment: I know C++ can do multiple inheritance, but really why do you need to reference it in such a manner?  Wouldn't it be better to structure the requirements a bit neater and cleaner.  Even implementing some Polymorphism would make it nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it written currently, `class C` would be deriving from `A` twice (once directly, and once indirectly from `B`)

Comment: Right. Multiple inheritance from the same base class is valid.

Comment: It says, identifier not found

Comment: @MelMed What identifier not found? You make it too difficult to help you.

Comment: Imagine I' m having a function called f_C, coming from C, and then I go to the class file where is A, and make C::f_C(....), it says identifier not found.

Comment: @mark, probably not as warnings are surpressable by using explicit syntax, and I don't see any way of rewriting this without adding an additional class.